# Faster way to find inverse for a given matrix with a particular structure

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $x_1,\dots,x_N$ be a set of $d\times 1$ vectors where $d$ is typically within $50$ and $N$ is in the range of $50000$'s. I construct the $N\times d$ matrix $X$ by stacking up $x_i$ as its rows, thus $$X=\begin{bmatrix}x_1^T \\\vdots \\ x_N^T\end{bmatrix}$$ Then consider the matrix $$B=I+XX^T$$ which is of dimension $N\times N$ and thus huge for my application. Is there a easier way to find inverse of this matrix than normal methods, may be exploiting its structure?